# Schopenhauer's contributions to modern science

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, physics, causality, schopenhauer

This topic will serve as a place where we collect modern (scientific) discoveries that Schopenhauer already anticipated or wrote about them. He is in this regard unparalleled in western philosophy.

Format:

```
<scientific discovery> -> <schopenhauers-equivalent-idea>
```

1. The Will -> Selfish gene
   @RichardDawkins
2. Sufficient Reason -> Explanation
   @DavidDeutschOxf
3. Understanding&Reason -> System 1&2
   @kahneman_daniel
4. Causal inference(Understanding) -> Unconscious inference/Predictive brain @Helmholtz
5. Subject&object -> Intentionality
   @JohnRSearle
6. Matter-Causality equivalence -> Mass-Energy equivalence
   @AlbertEinstein
7. Fundamental forces-Causality-Matter -> Entity-Component-System game architecture

Comment: Could you explain your examples further? E.g. how is Subject and Object a scientific discovery and why do you attribute intentionality to Schopenhauer?

Comment: @Johan https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108396/why-is-schopenhauers-definition-of-intentionality-not-generally-accepted-by-phi

Comment: Much of this long predates Schopenhauer. Intentionality goes back to medieval  scholastics, principle of sufficient reason was spelled out by Leibniz, reason and understanding are Kantian terms, etc. Even assuming that your loose associations can be made scientific use of, why do you think that scientists took them specifically from Schopenhauer?