Did Daniel Dennet plagiarize Schopenhauer?
Compare Dennett's 3 levels of explanations for behavior of objects with Schopenhauer's 3 forms of Causality.
Dennett is talking about an approach to explain the behaviour of objects.
Explanation is in Schopenhauer terms another name for sufficient Reason.
Behaviour of objects is another name for their acting which is Causality for Schopenahuer.



Maybe they both 'plagiarized' Aristotle's causes/explanations, material/efficient, formal and final, respectively. These sorts of things were generic platitudes in modern times.

I believe this summary of Dennet (the quoted one) may be tendentious. There is no big difference between an intentional, teleological or design stance. All of those boil down to the same thing, some assumption of aiming to achieve some end or realize some intention. Can you quote any of Dennett's own texts that make an explicit distinction in three rather than only two different stances instead of quoting someone else's summary? If we do make a distinction, then Schopenhauers "stimulus" doesn't quite seem the same as the "design" one (it suggests some form of vitalism).

@mudskipper The source is the Wikipedia article Intentional stance and the source in that source is: Dennett, D. C., (1987) "Three Kinds of Intentional Psychology", pp. 43–68 in Dennett, D. C., The Intentional Stance, The MIT Press, (Cambridge), 1987.   So it was Dennett himself who came up with the tripartite classification. Intentionality, as I am sure you know, has a particular meaning in philosopy. It is sometimes described as 'aboutness'. I think there is a huge difference between intentionality and teleology...

I see... Thanks for the references. But this is all just such a awful waste of time...

Regarding Intenitonality, it's just another term for Representation. This is sad episode in philosophy.
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108396/why-is-schopenhauers-definition-of-intentionality-not-generally-accepted-by-phi

Philosopher's borrow. This is quite common in the scholarly tradition. Sometimes it is referenced, though this is a recent innovation and at other times, if the borrowing is distant enough, it is not.
I wouldn't call this plaigarising unless it is actually is a word for word copy.

It's not recent phenomenon. Lot's of people tried to plagiarize Schopenhauer even when he was still alive. Famous example is Helmholtz whom Schopenhauer accused directly.
